# Google Drive / Gmail Aliases - Professional vs. Non-professional

Tags: gmail

I have a personal gmail account which I use for thousands of personal accounts - for security, recovery, etc...

If an employer would like to collaborate with me via google docs, I would like to be able to collaborate logged-into my personal email, but have a more professional email alias for google docs.

Is this possible?

i.e. If my employer asks me what my Gmail is, I'd like to give them a professionally-named email as opposed to one I named about cheetos and hamsters when I was young - but I'd still like to only have to login to one Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

From how I understand your question, your solution might be using a gmail alias. 
A gmail alias is: "Basically, an email alias is a different name you have for your email address. For instance, if your email address is realname@gmail.com, you can set up a separate address for fakename@gmail.com. Then, use the second as an alias when you don’t want to give out your primary address but still have the emails delivered to your main Gmail inbox."
[Here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/12/10/create-gmail-email-alias/) you can read more about it, and it has instruction to set it up too, if you find it useful.